# How to use interface in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made an interface that looks like this:

```
public interface Weapon
{
    void Shoot();
    float damage { get; set; }
}
```

And I implement it in another class and for damage field I have something like this:

```
   float Weapon.damage
    {
        get
        {
            return damage;
        }

        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

But How can I use the getter for Weapon.damage ? I tried something like this: Weapon.damage.get() but it didn't work

Any help will be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: I suggest that you learn some fundamentals of C#, especially about classes and interfaces.

Comment: Using interfaces with properties in Unity can be counter-productive, because you often want to adjust the values of variables through the inspector. Unity by default only serializes Fields, not Properties.

Comment: Immorality I would argue that you are forgetting about S.O.L.I.D. principles. Unity may have some specifics that make debugging difficult but you shouldn't let that affect your architecture. Maybe you need a namespace layer for .Unity objects that can be serialized easily

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with Code-Apprentice - you should take a look at other examples of fundamentals of classes & interfaces. For your specific item, you could do something like the following. I haven't tried to compile it but it should get you close

```
public interface IWeapon
{
    void Shoot();
    float Damage { get; }
}

public class Sword : IWeapon
{
    public void Shoot() { } //does nothing
    private float _damage { get; set; }
    public float Damage { get { return _damage; } }
    public Sword(int damage)
    {
        _damage = damage;
    }
}
```

Comment: `public float Damage { get; private set; }` is a thing.